# How to delete a specific snapshot using Powershell in Hyper-V

Tags: powershell, snapshot, hyper-v, checkpoint

Dears,

I am trying to delete a specific snapshot for one of our VMs but all the snapshots are being deleted instead.

```
PS C:\Users\abood>  Get-VMSnapshot -VMName KUW-HV01

VMName   Name SnapshotType CreationTime         ParentSnapshotName
------   ---- ------------ ------------         ------------------
KUW-HV01 OLD  Standard     7/22/2020 9:17:48 PM                   
KUW-HV01 NEW  Standard     7/22/2020 9:18:08 PM OLD  

PS C:\Users\abood>  Remove-VMSnapshot -VMName KUW-HV01 -WhatIf | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "NEW"}
What if: Remove-VMSnapshot will remove snapshot "NEW".
What if: Remove-VMSnapshot will remove snapshot "OLD".
```

How can i delete only "NEW" or "OLD" while keeping the other one?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most cmdlets that take an action against something (such as `Remove-VMSnapshot`) will allow you to pipe objects into them to specify what objects to take that action against. For example, you already used `Get-VMSnapshot` to get the two snapshots of that specific VM. You can then use `Where-Object` to specify only the snapshot you want to delete and filter out any that you want to keep like this:

```
Get-VMSnapshot -VMName KUW-HV01 | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "NEW"}

VMName   Name SnapshotType CreationTime         ParentSnapshotName
------   ---- ------------ ------------         ------------------
KUW-HV01 NEW  Standard     7/22/2020 9:18:08 PM OLD
```

Then you pipe that to `Remove-VMSnapshot` to specify exactly what you want to remove.

```
Get-VMSnapshot -VMName KUW-HV01 | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "NEW"} | Remove-VMSnapshot -WhatIf
```

That should result in this:

```
What if: Remove-VMSnapshot will remove snapshot "NEW".
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked but why "Remove-VMSnapshot -VMName KUW-HV01 -WhatIf | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "NEW"}" failed to work as intended? is that a bug or something?

Comment: No, not a bug at all. That command tells it to remove the snapshots (all of them, since you don't specify which one to the `Remove-VMSnapshot` cmdlet), and after that happens you send output to `Where-Object`. Honestly this could all be reduced to `Remove-VMSnapshot -VMName KUW-HV01 -Name NEW`, but I wanted to show you how `Where` works, and how it only affects things further down the pipeline, not things that come before it.

Comment: Ok now i understand. One last question, can i use wildcard naming in Remove-VMSnapshot -VMName KUW-HV01 -Name *NEW*?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/remove-vmsnapshot?view=win10-ps#examples) you can. They do it in their example that they give.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I appreciate your help.